Rider-Docker - Cant´t retrieve image id from build stream
I'm having difficulty building a Docker image using JetBrains Rider and Podman-Desktop. When I attempt to build the image, I receive the following error: "Can't retrieve image id from build stream."
Here are the details of my environment:
Development Environment: JetBrains Rider
I am using the Docker Service in Rider
Container Management: Podman-Desktop
I've already taken the following steps to try to resolve the issue:

Verified connection settings in Rider: In Rider, I went to Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Docker and ensured that the connection to my Docker host is correctly configured.

Analyzed error messages: I reviewed the detailed error messages in Rider but couldn't find any additional clues.

Checked network connection: There don't appear to be any network issues between my development environment and the Podman host.


Despite these steps, the problem persists. Does anyone have any ideas on what else I could try to resolve this issue?
Thank you in advance!
